# How to use subfolders with the FOR command?

Tags: file, batch-file

I'm trying to use the FOR /f command to calculate the filesize of multiple files with the same extension. I have this so far:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('C:\Users\%username%\*.bat') DO set size=%%~zA
```

If I have 3 batch files under the desktop, and 2 under my documents, I want the batch file to get the size of each and display all 5 together. I have the command working perfectly if I use just a single directory with batch files, but all I need is for it to include subdirectories. The current line I have above displays `ECHO is off` because there are NO batch files under the path `C:\Users\%username%.` I have batch files on my desktop, and I need it to include it since it's a subdirectory. How can I get this command to include subdirectories?

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html

Comment: User has posted here on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749372/for-r-using-set-a-variable-variable-za

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### FOR /R

Loop through files (Recurse subfolders)

Syntax

```
  FOR /R [[drive:]path] %%parameter IN (set) DO command
```

Key

```
drive:path  : The folder tree where the files are located.

set         : A set of one or more files. Wildcards must be used.
              If (set) is a period character (.) then FOR will
              loop through every folder.

command     : The command(s) to carry out, including any
              command-line parameters.

%%parameter : A replaceable parameter:
              in a batch file use %%G (on the command line %G)
```

This command walks down the folder tree starting at [drive:]path, and executes the DO statement against each matching file.

If the [drive:]path are not specified they will default to the current drive:path.

Unlike some other variants of the FOR command you must include a wildcard (either * or ?) in the 'set' to get consistent results returned. In many cases you can work around this by adding a single character wildcard e.g. if you are looping through multiple folders to find the exact filename myfile.txt you could instead specify `myfile.t?t`

http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html

Answer (score 0):

dir is far easier.

```
dir "%userprofile%\*.bat" /a /s
```

or just the sizes

```
dir "%userprofile%\*.bat" /a /s|findstr /c:"File(s)"
```

Comment: Sure, if all you want is a directory listing.