# FOR /R - Using set /a [variable] = [variable] + %%~zA

Tags: file, batch-file

I've got a command to loop and set the file size of each file with a specific extension under a directory and all subdirectories:

```
FOR /R "C:\Users" %%G IN (*.*) do set /a size = %size% + %%~zG
```

I would like the command to use the %size% + %%!zG when looping, but when I run the batch file, the output constantly has "%size%" set to 0. I want to have all the file sizes that are searched to add up, not just stay 0. What happens at the very end, is %size% is set to the very last file "scanned".

For some reason it says "0" constantly and it doesn't add up each "loop". THank you! All responses are appreciated.

Comment: Please be aware that Windows batch numbers are limited to ~2 gigabytes. You are likely to run across folders where the total file size exceeds 2GB. You may even run into a single file that exceeds the maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /R "C:\Users" %%G IN (*.*) do set /a size = !size! + %%~zG
```

In for loops you can not refer to environment variables normally.

#### Edit:

Just realised we were using `set /a` **!!!!!!!**

```
FOR /R "C:\Users" %%G IN (*.*) do set /a size+=%%~zG
```

Much better way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you! You are a life saver! I love this website.

Comment: +1, Definitely the edit version is the way to go :-)